# Is there a way to assign a button to move through textfields

Tags: swift, button, uitextfield

There are 3 textfields. By default the first will be selected once program launches. There is a next button where by pressing it, the next textfield would be selected. For some reason it is crashing. Crashes the moment the button is pressed. Can someone explain what i am doing wrong

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            //select default
            textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
            }

    //should go to next textfield when pressed
    @IBAction func NextButton()
    {

        // if textfield is selected
        if(textfield.becomeFirstResponder() == true)
        {
            textfield.resignFirstResponder()
            textfieldTwo.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        if(textfieldTwo.becomeFirstResponder() == true)
        {
            textfieldTwo.resignFirstResponder()
            textfieldThree.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can make a textField active by `textField.becomeFirstResponder()`

Comment: How would you go to next textfield using a next button?

Comment: You could put them in an array and the select the next one

Comment: how do you deselect it then?

Comment: The will get deselected when you select another one. Only one can be active at the time. If you want to be sure you could also call `textField.resignFirstResponder`

Comment: For some reason it crashes evey time the button is pressed
    //should go to next textfield when pressed
    @IBAction func NextButton() {

        // if textfield is selected
        if(textfield.becomeFirstResponder() == true){
            textfield.resignFirstResponder()
            textfieldTwo.becomeFirstResponder()
            }

Comment: Please put code in your question, not in the comments, and mark on what line it crashes and what the error message is. That being said, you should use `isFirstResponder()`

Comment: just added to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `becomeFirstResponder()` to check if a textfield is active, instead use `isFirstResponder()`. Also note I added the `else if` for `textfieldTwo`.

```
@IBAction func NextButton()
{
    // if textfield is selected
    if(textfield.isFirstResponder() == true)
    {
        textfield.resignFirstResponder()
        textfieldTwo.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    else if(textfieldTwo.isFirstResponder() == true)
    {
        textfieldTwo.resignFirstResponder()
        textfieldThree.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```